# Domain.com/path redirects to www.domain.com using heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting

My Host records are:

@ http://www.domain.io URL Redirect
www app_name.herokuapp.com. CNAME (Alias)

I'm sharing domain.io/path and it's redirecting to www.domain.io rather than reaching the path

www.domain.io/path it's successful

Namecheap suggests that it is an issue on the heroku side

Thanks for the help

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: This doesn't refer to this issue that I'm having does it?